# setting session id variable from sql database; is this safe?

Tags: php, sql, session, session-variables

Is it unsafe to use the user_id in my sql table as the session id? is this normally what php developers do?

[image]
<sub>(source: [sockface.com](http://sockface.com/hellooooo.png))</sub>

Also I've tried countless times to store the session id as the user id

```
include('profile/core/init_inc.php');    
$_SESSION['uid'] = $user_id;
header("Location: profile/edit_profile.php");
```

in my init_inc

```
function fetch_user_info($uid){
$uid = (int)$uid;

$sql = "SELECT
            `user_id` AS `id`,
            `username`,
            `user_firstname` AS `firstname`,
            `user_lastname` AS `lastname`,
            `user_about` AS `about`,
            `user_email` AS `email`
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `user_id` = {$uid}";

$result = mysql_query($sql);        
return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

If i have     $_SESSION['uid'] = 90; it will display test@test.ca info [here](http://goawaymom.com/login/logon.php) after you log on

so my question is, is it safe to store the session id as the user_id, and how come when i try to do it, why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

1.) A session ID should not be a constant value for a particular user. That is a security violation. The session ID should change every once in a while. Ideally, it should be a random value.

2.) It doesn't look like you are setting the session ID. You are setting the session variable called "uid".

3.) Did you ever call `session_start()`?

---

Despite the fact that I really would not recommend setting a session ID to a constant value, you can set the ID for a session using the [session_id() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php):

```
$session_id = "some_random_value";
session_id($session_id);
```

But like I said, this should not be the user's ID. You can store the user's ID as session information, and check that when the user loads a page to see if they are logged in.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"]))
{
    //user is logged in
    $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
}
else
{
    //make user log in
    $user_id = result_of_login();
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
}
```

More information on PHP sessions in the [session documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: why is it a security violation, what am i to do instead?

Comment: If the session ID for a user is always the same, then it would be must easier for a malicious user to hijack the user's sessions. PHP generates random session IDs for you, so you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: Hmmm, how come when i log on then and try to edit profile it doesn't know what user I'm logged on as.

Comment: You should store the user's login information in the session data. However, the session ID should not be the user's ID.